# How to raise an IndexError when slice indices are out of range?

Tags: python, exception, indexing, slice

The [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError) states that

> *slice indices* are silently truncated to fall in the *allowed range*

and therefor no `IndexErrors` are risen when slicing a list, regardless what `start` or `stop` parameters are used:

```
>>> egg = [1, "foo", list()]
>>> egg[5:10]
[]
```

Since the list *`egg` does not contain any indices greater then `2`*, a `egg[5]` or `egg[10]` call would raise an `IndexError`:

```
>> egg[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The question is now, *how can we raise an `IndexError`, when both given slice indices are out of range?*

Comment: Why not? Because an empty slice result is still a valid object. If you want to raise exceptions, probe the start and end indices manually, or explicitly test for `len(egg)` against your boundaries.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thanks for your reply! I am not sure if this is a duplicate because I ask about "*How to raise an IndexError when slice a sequence*" and not the "*Why slicing index out of range works*". But correct me If I am wrong :)

Comment: You asked **two** questions, making your post too broad. I duped you to a previous question that answers the first, and provided your options to answer the second.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ok I see, I have a edited my question...

Comment: So when should an exception be raised? When both indices are out of bounds? For any indices that result in an empty slice? What should happen with negative indices? For slices where the start point >= end point and the stride isn't negative? Please be more specific as to why you want the error to be raised, because there are different scenarios that you may see as an error.

Comment: As I said "I want to raise an exception when **both of the given slice indices are out of range**". In all other cases the result would be the same as a "normal" size and return an empty list if a slice is not possible.

Comment: Then just test for both indices against the length of the list and raise an exception manually when both are out of range. You'll have to handle the `None` and negative cases, but that's it. There is no magic bullet here.

Comment: Thanks :) Ok that was exactly my question.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 2 you can override `__getslice__` method by this way:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getslice__(self, i, j):
        len_ = len(self)
        if i > len_ or j > len_:
            raise IndexError('list index out of range')
        return super(MyList, self).__getslice__(i, j)
```

Then use your class instead of `list`:

```
>>> egg = [1, "foo", list()]
>>> egg = MyList(egg)
>>> egg[5:10]
Traceback (most recent call last):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Note `j` can be `sys.maxsize`! For `egg[5:]` or `egg[5:None]` your code raises `IndexError` where that's **not an invalid index**. You can add `if j == sys.maxsize: j = len_` to work around this, but note that someone using `egg[5:sys.maxsize]` then won't get an `IndexError`. That's the downside of using `__getslice__`; that and it no longer exists in Python 3!

Answer (score 3):

There is no silver bullet here; you'll have to test both boundaries:

```
def slice_out_of_bounds(sequence, start=None, stop=None, step=1):
    length = len(sequence)
    if start is None:  # default depends on step direction
        start = length - 1 if step < 0 else 0
    elif start < 0:  # relative to length
        start += length
    if stop is None:  # default depends on step direction
        stop = -1 if step < 0 else length
    elif stop < 0:  # relative to length
        stop += length
    # stop can range [0 .. length] for positive steps or
    # [-1 .. (length - 1)] for negative steps (both bounds inclusive).
    # adjust stop for negative steps to make the bounds check easier.
    if step < 0:
        stop += 1
    if not (0 <= start < length and 0 <= stop <= length):
        raise IndexError("Container slice indices out of bounds")
```

Note the way we need to handle `stop` specially. The end value in slicing is *exclusive*, so is allowed to range up to `length`. For negative strides, valid `stop` values lie in the range `[-1 .. length)` (or `[-1 .. (length - 1)]` with inclusive bounds), but adding 1 to the `stop` value makes it possible to re-use the same `0 <= stop <= length` test.

If you create your own container class with an [`__getitem__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), then slicing the container gives you a [`slice()` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice). Don't use the [`slice.indices()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices) in that case, it adjusts the bounds for you rather than raise an `IndexError`. Instead, us the `.start`, `.stop` and `.step` attributes. Each of those can be `None`, including `.step`, so make sure to handle that too.

Here's a `__getitem__` version of the above, with a few added checks for other edge cases to replicate how `list` slicing works:

```
class SomeContainer:
    ...

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        length = len(self)

        if isinstance(key, int) and not (0 <= key < length):
            raise IndexError("Container index out of range")

        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            if key.step == 0:
                raise ValueError("Slice step cannot be zero")
            start, stop, step = key.start, key.stop, key.step or 1
            if start is None:  # default depends on step direction
                start = length - 1 if step < 0 else 0
            elif start < 0:  # relative to length
                start += length
            if end is None:  # default depends on step direction
                end = -1 if step < 0 else length
            elif end < 0:  # relative to length
                end += length
            # end can range [0 .. length] for positive steps or
            # [-1 .. (length - 1)] for negative steps (both bounds inclusive).
            # adjust end for negitive steps to make the bounds check easier.
            # Don't do this if you also wanted to calculate the slice length!
            if step < 0:
                end += 1
            if not (0 <= start < length and 0 <= end <= length):
                raise IndexError("Container slice indices out of bounds")

         else:
            raise TypeError(f"list indices must be integers or slices, not {type(key)}")
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding length to either `start` or `end` if they're negative, instead of `length - (-start)`. Also if doing negative indexing, `start = length - 1` and `stop = -1`

Comment: @pseudovella: good catch! Yes, adding, not subtracting, is needed. I've rewritten the code to avoid those issues, including exposition about negative strides and the stop boundaries.